# how to get a list of all FCurves in a scene

Tags: python, animation

for the addon I'm working on, I need a list of all fcurves (a list of all selected/visible fcurves would be enouph)
Do I really have to loop through all animation_data objects to get this list?

Thanks in advance,
Jacques Lucke

Comment: see [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28005/how-do-i-know-if-i-have-a-selected-keyframe-using-python) it is almost the same

Comment: so it's OK to close this as a duplicate ?

Comment: @Chebhou Questions should be closed if the *question* is the same, not because one may have an answer which is the same. The questions are quite different imo. See: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/549/duplicate-answer-vs-duplicate-question

Comment: @RayMairlot good point, ok i'm voting to reopen

Answer (score 5):

#### F-Curves via Actions

You can use `bpy.data.actions` to get a list of all F-Curves in the scene, but **actions are not associated with objects, scenes or nodes**:

```
for i in bpy.data.actions:
    print (i.name)
    for fcu in i.fcurves:
        print (fcu)
        for keyframe in fcu.keyframe_points:
            x, y = keyframe.co
            print (x,y)
```

It's only possible to check if the actual object is associated with an action via [**animation_data**](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=animation%20data#bpy.types.Object.animation_data) in a reverse operation with `Object.animation_data.action` to get something like: `bpy.data.actions['Action']`. Another option is to check `animation_data.action.name`.

---

If you need to know **which F-Curve is applied to objects or nodes in your scene**, the only way is to use [**animation_data**](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=animation%20data#bpy.types.Object.animation_data) and iterate through all components like:

- `Object.animation_data` *- F-Curves of an Object*
- `Scene.animation_data` *- F-Curves of the Scene*
- `Material.animation_data` *- F-Curves of a Material*
- ...

#### F-Curves of an Object

```
import bpy
import math

obj = bpy.context.active_object
keyframes = []

anim = obj.animation_data
if anim is not None and anim.action is not None:
    for fcu in anim.action.fcurves:
        print (fcu)
        for keyframe in fcu.keyframe_points:
            x, y = keyframe.co
            print (x,y)
            if x not in keyframes:
                keyframes.append((math.ceil(x)))
```

To get the **F-Curves of all objects in the scene** you can use `bpy.data.objects` and iterate through the objects in the scene like:

```
object_list = bpy.data.objects

for i in object_list:
    anim = i.animation_data
    if anim is not None and anim.action is not None:
        for fcu in anim.action.fcurves:
            print (fcu)
```

#### F-Curves of a Node Shader

```
obj = bpy.context.object

shader = obj.data.materials[0].node_tree
anim_data = shader.animation_data

for fcu in anim_data.action.fcurves:
    print (fcu)
    for keyframe in fcu.keyframe_points:
        x, y = keyframe.co
        print (x,y)
```

Comment: Thanks, the important thing you forgot here is that not onlyobjects can have keyframes but also scenes, nodes...

Comment: @JacquesLucke thanks for clearification. Iteration should be the same - but I'll try to update the code as soon as I can.